# What was the largest object/particle tunneling observed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-tunneling

What is a current record? Reference to that would be nice. and what can be expected in near future? what are the theoretical limits?

Comment: I can't give you a reference, but I am afraid that your notion of tunneling as a Guinness book of records kind of affair is way off. The limits are given by the quantum mechanical tunneling formula. For any given mass one can find combinations of tunneling barrier height, thickness and energy for which tunneling is both possible and a completely trivial process because the tunneling thickness would be far smaller than the physical dimension of the body. You can experiment with it here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html: Hint: start by picking $\alpha x=1$.

Comment: There is the assumption that passing through the barrier for a particular object and potential depends only on the energy of the object. Quantum tunnelling is only an illustration that in QM there is no solution with zero probability.

Comment: You can read about the largest recorded tunneling object here:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertha_%28tunnel_boring_machine%29

Comment: And yes, I do know that's not what you meant.

Comment: @Asher Wow, that's a big tunnel.

Comment: @CuriousOne Ok, thats probably best answer to what I asked. Maybe a better explanation what motivated my question. I got a feeling that experimentalists are kind of competing to put as large objects as possible in superposition states and that way demonstrate QM at large(nano) scale. So I was wondering if there are also people who try to demonstrate QM for large(nano) objects by tunneling them. I guess your link can tell me how reasonable this is.

Comment: There is no competition for the system with the largest quantum state. We can build superconducting magnets of almost any size we want (it's just a matter of money) and it is very likely that light stays coherent across the distance of the entire visible universe. Why would you want to compete with that?

Comment: @CuriousOne: they even came up with measure for macroscopicity of quantum state. http://physics.aps.org/synopsis-for/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.160403

Comment: You don't have to buy into every nutty thing individuals who are clueless about reality do, not even in physics and not even when Phys. Rev. Lett. picks it up.

Comment: @CuriousOne I would say that field is fairly large, rather than it is about only few individuals. Whether it is nutty, dunno.

Comment: Still I would like to see some experiment preparing macroscoping objects in superposition states.

Comment: Have you been in a superconducting magnet in the MRI machine in your local hospital? That magnet is in one macroscopic quantum state, you are simply not aware of that. Seriously, some people have too much time on their hands to consider nonsensical questions like where the line is between the quantum and the classical world. There is no such line, it's ALL one quantum world, you just don't see it all the time. Once you are trained to know the phenomenology of these things doing a quantum experiment is as trivial as making a hole in aluminum foil and holding it in sunlight.

Comment: [ADVISORY: There is a nonzero probability that, through a process known as tunnelling, your computer may spontaneously leave your domicile and reappear in your neighbour's. The manufacturer will not be responsible for any damage or inconvenience that may result from such a move.](http://physics.open.ac.uk/~dbroadhu/warn.htm)

Comment: 1) We already have observed large objects exhibit tunneling effects. The current in a dc SQUID hundreds of microns across can be seen to tunnel from one state to another. 2) @CuriousOne, your statement about magnets being in a quantum state is just vague enough to maybe be correct, but I think not. Sitting in a single ground state isn't particularly "quantum" even if quantum mechanics is used to understand that state. Superposed *excitations* and entanglement are where you see something classical mechanics can't explain.

Comment: @CuriousOne 3) The statement that everything is quantum with no boundary between quantum and classical is contentious at best. It's certainly attractive from the aesthetic and Occam's razor perspectives, and there is some relatively recent data suggesting that it may be right, but it's very difficult to reconcile that notion with the fact that the data shows that wave functions collapse in a non-unitary way. Decoherence gets you close to resolution, but not quite all the way. I think it best not to misrepresent this issue with such authoritative language.

Comment: With massless particles, this is rather simple. I have tunneled microwaves through ~3 cm barriers (classically they should have gone through total internal reflection).

Answer (score 1):

Stars are a great example.

[image]

Quantum tunneling is basically just getting over an energy barrier that is unpenetrable in classical mechanics. Stars survive off of this phenomena. Stars usually do not have enough energy to fuse hydrogen into helium. The hydrogen atoms (a small percent, but since there are so many atoms, it matters) tunnel over the energy barrier and fuse.

Comment: +1 for the answer but the image is doubtful. Classical stones must stay behind while a few quantum ones may climb up the hill

Comment: @igael I tried t point that out in the answer, but yeah, the image is a little misleading.

Comment: Thats more like a lot of small particles tunneling independently?

Comment: @sa101 As opposed to a big rock tunneling? That's never been observed.

Comment: @Jimmy360 I was more thinking about macromolecules or nanospheres...

Answer (score -2):

In some sense, there is some kind of classical tunneling. For example, a high jumper, if (s)he bends her/his body over the bar, can pass over the bar in such a way that its center of gravity is always below the bar, and his kinetic + potential energy is always less than mgh, where m is her/his mass and h is the height of the bar. See, e.g.,  A. Cohn, M. Rabinowitz, Classical Tunneling, Int'l Journ. Theor. Phys., v. 29, #3, 1990, p. 215.